# The Number Of Integer Solutions Of Equations With Constraints

Tags: combinatorics, vectors

This question contains formulas from my previous question  [The Number Of Integer Solutions Of Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919676/the-number-of-integer-solutions-of-equations).

---

I understand the following thus far:

1. The number of distinct **positive** integer-valued vectors $(x_1,x_2,...,x_r)$ such that $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$$
   is equal to $n-1\choose r-1$.
2. The number of distinct **non-negative** integer-valued vectors $(x_1,x_2,...,x_r)$ such that $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$$
   is equal to $n+r-1\choose r-1$.

---

- **Problem 1**

  Suppose I want to count the number of distinct integer-valued vectors of the form $(x_1, x_2,...,x_r)$ such that $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$$

  But now there are constraints involved $$x_1 \geq 0$$ $$x_r \geq 0$$ $$x_i > 0, i = 2,...,r-1 $$

  In words: the first and last integers are greater or equal to zero and all in-between must be greater than zero.

  *How many such distinct vectors are possible?*
- **My Approach To Problem 1**

  Let $$y_1 = x_1 + 1$$ $$y_i =  x_i, i = 2,...,r-1$$ $$y_r = x_r + 1$$

  This gives the **positive** integer-valued vector of the form $(y_1, y_2, ... , y_r)$ such that $$y_1 + y_2 + ... + y_r = n + 2$$

  By **(1)**, the number of distinct integer-valued vectors is equal to $n+2-1\choose r-1$ $=$ $n+1\choose r-1 $

---

- **Problem 2**

  Suppose I want to count the number of distinct integer-valued vectors of the form $(x_1, x_2,...,x_r)$ such that $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$$

  The constraints involved are $$x_1 \geq 0$$ $$x_i \geq 2,  i = 2,...,r-1 $$ $$x_r \geq 0$$

  In words: the first and last integers are greater or equal to zero and all in-between are greater or equal to two.

  *How many such distinct vectors are possible?*
- **My Approach To Problem 2**

  Let $$y_1 = x_1 + 1$$ $$y_i =  x_i + 2, i = 2,...,r-1$$ $$y_r = x_r + 1$$

  This gives the **positive** integer-valued vector of the form $(y_1, y_2, ... , y_r)$ such that $$y_1 + y_2 + ... + y_r = n + 2 + 2(r-2) = n + 2r-2$$

  By **(1)**, the number of distinct integer-valued vectors is equal to $n+2r-2-1\choose r-1$ $=$ $n+2r-3\choose r-1 $

---

**I would appreciate it if you could verify my solutions and provide hints/suggestions.**

Comment: In problem 2, perhaps you mean to define $y_i=x_i-1$, when $i=2,\ldots,r-1$? Otherwise using your current definition, $y_i=x_i+2\geq2+2=4$, when $i=2,\ldots,r-1$.

Comment: @Peter That makes sense now, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is right, and well explained.

I don't like the $y_i$ for the second. Either let $y_i=x_i-2$ for the middle ones, and use the formula for the number of solutions in non-negative integers of a suitable equation, or let $y_i=x_i+1$ for the end ones, and $y_i=x_i-1$ for the middle ones, and use the formula for the number of positive solutions of a suitable equation.

Comment: At this moment I can't seem to figure out where the $-2$ in $y_i = x_i -2$ and the $-1$ in $y_i = x_i -1$ comes from?

Comment: Wait, $-2$ for the non-negative since at least $2$ needs to be added to $y_i$ for the equation to be suited for using **(2)**, and similarly for $-1$ and positive integer-valued vector?

Comment: It depends on whether we want to reduce the problem to $\sum y_i=A$, with $y_i\ge 0$, or $\sum y_i=B$, where $y_i\ge 1$. Let's do the first. We want to distribute $n$ identical candies to $r$ kids, so that Kids $2$ to $r-1$ get $\ge 2$ candies. So give them each $2$ cndies, and distribute the remaining $n-2(r-2)$ among the $r$ kids, with possibly some getting $0$ in the second distribution. Of course this only works for $r\ge 2$.

Comment: If we want to use the formula for the number of solutions where everybody is $\ge 1$, then $x_1=y_1-1$, since we must allow $x_1=0$, same for $y_r$. For the middle ones, we need $y_i=x_i-1$ since $x_i\ge 2$. We end up finding the number of positive solutions of $\sum  y_i=n-(r-2)+2$.

Comment: It makes sense now. I used some horrible reasoning for problem 2 I now realize, I literally stopped thinking about what I was actually doing.

Comment: I value your assistance and the insight you have given me so much.

Comment: So I take it everything is clear? Your analysis of the first problem was good. The analyses I gave for the second problem really only use ideas that you used in the first.

Comment: Crystal clear. I know why I thought what I thought that led to the incorrect solution and I understand the solutions for both cases you provided.