# How to find the number of configurations are possible in this scenario

Tags: combinatorics

If you have 3 card spots on the table. The left and right spots can hold any number of cards, the middle can only hold at most 1 at all times. How many starting configurations are possible for n cards?

Could someone show me how to solve this?

Comment: Are the left and the right spots identical in each and every aspect?

Comment: Well...suppose the middle slot is empty.  Can you solve it then?  What if you put a card in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You need to count the number of integer solutions of the equation: $$x_1+x_2+x_3=n$$ subject to the constraints $0\le x_1,0\le x_3$ and $0\le x_2\le 1$. Since the constraint for $x_2$ is rather simple, you can take two cases and add the results:

- Case 1: $x_2=0$. Count the number of integer solutions of $$x_1+x_3=n$$ subject to $0\le x_1,x_3$,
- Case 2: $x_2=1$. Count the number of integer solutions of $$x_1+1+x_3=n \iff x_1+x_3=n-1$$ subject to $0\le x_1,x_3$.

Both cases are now typical [star and bars problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925590/the-number-of-integer-solutions-of-equations-with-constraints). To obtain the solution just sum up the number of solutions of each case.

Comment: Im still stuck :/ Shouldnt the formula involve the combinations formula?

Comment: Sorry for this trouble, could you show me the final combinations formula. I am still having trouble building the combinations formula. An explanation would be great.

Comment: I dont get how you came up with the numbers within the brackets. How come there are not factorials if it is a combinations formula.

Comment: It seems to me that give not enough effort. The lower term is equal to $1$ so the factorials simplify. Did you try it? And the combinations come from the stars and bars theory.

Comment: Could you show me the non simplified version in the combinations formulas format, so with the factorial smybol. That would really help me understand this. I think once I see it in that form I will be able to get understand.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I did not understand that this was your question. Take the second one for example: $$\dbinom{n-1+2-1}{2-1}=\dbinom{n}{1}=\frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!}=\frac{n(n-1)!}{(n-1)!}=n$$

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would be the final answer right ? (n!/1!(n−1)!) + ((n!/1!(n−1)!) - 1)

Comment: No, sorry to say it so bluntly, but your math skills are very poor: $$\dbinom{n+2-1}{2-1}=\dbinom{n+1}{1}=\frac{(n+1)!}{1(n+1-1)!}=\frac{(n+1)n!}{n!}=n+1$$ So, final answer $$\dbinom{n+2-1}{2-1}+\dbinom{n-1+2-1}{2-1}=\dbinom{n+1}{1}+\dbinom{n}1=(n+1)+n=2n+1$$ I hope, I did not miscalculate. This worked for today, but will not get you very far...

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now. I final question, the only doubt I have is, how are you getting 2-1 in the denominator and numerator ?

Comment: Number $2$ comes from the two variables $x_1,x_3$ that you have on the LHS of the equation. Now, for more, just open your textbook on stars and bars or just open the wikipedia page or just google it!! You need to read the theory of stars and bars somehow! I also gave you a link in math.stackexchange above. Do you expect to learn the whole theory from the comments????