# References for the (Maclaurin) power series of $e^{\arcsin(x)} $?

Tags: reference-request, power-series

On p. 60 of Wilf's “[Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)”, it is stated that $$e^{\arcsin(x)}  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (4j^{2}+1) }{(2k)!}x^{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{4^{k} \prod_{j=0}^{k} ((1/2) - j + j^{2}) }{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}.$$
I wonder whether there are any references for this identity, preferably including a deviation. It would be great if the references also included (proofs for) related power series, including those of $e^{\arccos(x)}$ and $e^{\arctan(x)}$.

Comment: Related (the answer, not the question):  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820751

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a reference, but it is easy to verify that the function $g(x) = \exp(\arcsin(x))$ satisfies the differential equation
$$ (x^2-1) g'' + x g' + g = 0,\; g(0)=1,\; g'(0)=1$$
from which you can obtain a linear recurrence for its Maclaurin series coefficients:
$$ (n^2+1) a_n - (n+1)(n+2) a_{n+2} = 0, \; a_0 = 1,\; a_1 = 1 $$
and see that the given formula satisfies the recurrence.

Since $\arccos(x) = \pi/2 - \arcsin(x) = \pi/2 + \arcsin(-x)$, it is easy to get the series for $\exp(\arccos(x))$.
As for $\exp(\arctan(x))$, similar methods find the recurrence to be
$$ n a_n - a_{n+1} + (n+2) a_{n+2} = 0,\; a_0 = 1,\; a_1 = 1 $$
See [OEIS sequence A002019](https://oeis.org/A002019).

Answer (score 0):

The generating expression for the series expansion of $(\arcsin x)^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{e}^{t\arcsin x}=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\frac{b_\ell(t)x^\ell}{\ell!},
\end{equation*}
where $b_0(t)=1$, $b_1(t)=t$, and
\begin{equation*}
b_{2\ell}(t)=\prod_{k=0}^{\ell-1}\bigl[t^2+(2k)^2\bigr], \quad b_{2\ell+1}(t)=t\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}\bigl[t^2+(2k-1)^2\bigr]
\end{equation*}
for $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$. Another expression is
\begin{equation}\label{arcsin-pochhammer-binomial}
\begin{split}
\operatorname{e}^{2a\arcsin x}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-2\operatorname{i})^k \frac{\Gamma\bigl(\operatorname{i}a+\frac{k}{2}\bigr)}{\Gamma(\operatorname{i}a)} \frac{\Gamma(\operatorname{i}a+1)}{\Gamma\bigl(\operatorname{i}a-\frac{k}{2}+1\bigr)}\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
&=1+\operatorname{i}a\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-2\operatorname{i})^k \binom{\operatorname{i}a+\frac{k}{2}-1}{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
These expressions can be found in the following references.

References

1. B. C. Berndt, *Ramanujan's Notebooks, Part I*, With a foreword by S. Chandrasekhar, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1985, pp. 262--263.; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1088-7.
2. J. M. Borwein and M. Chamberland, *Integer powers of arcsin*, Int. J. Math. Math. Sci. **2007**, Art. ID 19381, 10 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1155/2007/19381.
3. A. I. Davydychev and M. Yu. Kalmykov, *New results for the $\varepsilon$-expansion of certain one-, two- and three-loop Feynman diagrams*, Nuclear Phys. B **605** (2001), no. 1-3, 266--318; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/S0550-3213(01)00095-5.
4. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
5. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Series expansions of powers of arcsine, closed forms for special values of Bell polynomials, and series representations of generalized logsine functions*, AIMS Mathematics **6** (2021), no. 7, 7494--7517; available online at https://doi.org/10.3934/math.2021438.
6. E. R. Hansen, *A Table of Series and Products*, Prentice-Hall, Englewood Cliffs, NJ, USA, 1975, pp. 210--211.
7. M. Yu. Kalmykov and A. Sheplyakov, *lsjk---a C++ library for arbitrary-precision numeric evaluation of the generalized log-sine functions*, Computer Phys. Commun. **172** (2005), no. 1, 45--59; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2005.04.013.