# Deduce, the Taylor series expansion of $\arcsin x$ from the Taylor Series expansion of $e^{a\arcsin x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, inverse-function

Find the Taylor Series expansion of $e^{a\arcsin x}$ and hence deduce, the Taylor series expansion of $\arcsin x$.

I could find the Taylor Series expansion of $e^{a\arcsin x}$ as $$1+ax+\frac{a^2x^2}{2}+\frac{a^3+a}{6}x^3+\cdots $$

However, I have no idea how to deduce the series for $\arcsin x$ from the above expansion. I tried writing, $e^{a\arcsin x}$ as $$1+a\arcsin x+\frac{(a\arcsin x)^2}{2!}+\cdots$$ and comparing the coefficients with the one above, but it was not of any help because , I only got the inference that, $x=\arcsin x$ which was quite obvious. Any help regarding solving this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: coefficient of $a$.

Comment: Take the logarithm and continue with Taylor series.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I tried it, but it doesn't seem to help me in any way.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: @ThomasFinley You have the Taylor series for $\exp(a\arcsin x)$, which you can regard as a series in $a$ with coefficient being a series in $x$.  So look the coefficient of $a$, which gives you $\arcsin x=x+\frac16 x^3+\dots$

Comment: @user10354138 I think I am at a loss of my wits, so I couldn't get you. But thanks!

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}e^{a\arcsin(x)}$ at $a=0$? Apply that to the power series you've found.

Comment: Finding Taylor series for $\exp(a\arcsin x) $ is rather tricky. See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657863/72031 (it does not have a proof but gives references). After that you need to compare coefficients of $a$ on both sides. The technique however is just formal manipulation of series and not rigorous. The same technique can be used to compare binomial series for $(1+x)^a$ and exponential series for $\exp(a\log(1+x))$ and then using coefficients of $a$ we get the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: A much better approach is to use the formula $\arcsin x=\int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ and justify term by term integration.

Comment: Another approach is to use a reduction formula for $\int_0^x\sin^{2n-1}t\,dt$ and integrate it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm not sure what your objection is.  Robert's answer on that page can be easily adapted to our case (with $(x^2-1)y''+xy'+a^2y=0$), and it is rigourous if you know enough complex analysis (several complex variables) to conclude the series expansion at $(a,x)=(0,0)$ converges on a small bidisc in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and so you can do all these manipulations.

Comment: @user10354138: I don't have any objections if the details you mention in your comment are presented. But most intro calculus texts don't do that and leave students gasping for breath by providing such arguments. See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1869524/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh "The technique however is ... not rigorous" is a very different from "intro to calculus texts don't do that rigorously".  With that frame of reference, you must also be saying, e.g., sufficient statistics from Fisher-Neyman factorisation as "not rigorous" because most intro to mathematical statistics textbook don't give the measure-theoretic treatment that is Halmos-Savage; or change of variables in multiple integrals is not rigorous because again most calculus textbook doesn't prove it rigorously with Jordan measure etc but just with "volume element"?

Comment: Unless one supplies the details or mentions about them being available in suitable references, it is not really rigorous. How else does one judge the rigor of a content present in any math textbook? However I think we are digressing here and I won't comment further.