# Best method to find how many solutions are there to the equation $a + b + c = 21?$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The positive integers $a, b, $ and $c$ are such that $ a + b + c =21$.

$a = 5, b = 5, c = 11$ is a solution. $a = 5, b = 11, c = 5$ is another solution (i.e. order matters).

How many different solutions are there?

I can see a very slow way of writing each individual case out, but this is definitely not ideal... Is there a faster way?

Comment: Have you tried using stars and bars?

Comment: What does "stars and bars" refer to?

Comment: You'll want to read this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919676/the-number-of-integer-solutions-of-equations

Comment: See this [Brilliant page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/). The formula is for non-negative integers, but you can transform the equation by defining new variables $a' = a - 1, b' = b-1$ and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=1$ there are 19 ways to choose $b$ and then only one way to choose $c$.

If $a=2$ there are 18 ways to choose $b$ and then only one way to choose $c$.

If $a=3$ there are 17 ways to choose $b$ and then only one way to choose $c$.

This pattern clearly continues, so there are $19 + 18 + 17 + … + 1$ ways altogether. This is simply an arithmetic series with first term 19, and common difference 1, so its sum is (20 x 19)/2. Hence your answer is 190.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to think about this:

Do you remember how tally's work: | = 1 || = 2 and ||| = 3.. and so forth. Let's take that but ||||| = 5, there are no diagonals.

There are going to be 21 tallies and 2 plus signs to achieve the sum of 21, so of 23 spots, we choose 21 to be the places we put the tallies. Or we can choose 2 of 23 spots to choose the plus signs.

But wait! The numbers - a, b, c - have to be positive as you specified. So let's declare variables $a = a_* + 1$, $b = b_* + 1$, $c = c_* + 1$.

Substituting this into the equation:  $a + b + c = 21$
$$a_* + b_* + c_* = 18$$

So there are 20 spots to choose from (18 bars and 2 "+"'s). So the answer to your question is ${{20} \choose 2} = {{20} \choose 18}$

Answer (score 1):

Read this article on [combinatorial compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) to understand how the general problem is solved. The answer is $$\binom{21-1}{3-1}=\binom{20}{2}=\frac{20\cdot 19}{2}=190.$$