# Number of arrangements with 5 men and 5 women in which no two men are seated next to each other

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to arrange 5 men and 5 women such that no two men are seated next to each other. My idea was to count the number of ways I can seat them all with 2 men being together and subtract $10!$ (ways to seat them). The answer to this problem according to Robert Bartoszynski is 86,400.
My calculations are:
$$ \#\text{ ways to arrange} = 10! \ - (_5P_2 * 9!) $$
Obviously this is negative and I'm wondering where is my mistake.
I'm searching for a solution using the last idea.

Comment: Arrangements where there are multiple pairs of men sitting together are being overcounted in your computation.

Comment: Who is Robert Bartoszynski?

Comment: @Viktor Glombik the author's

Comment: @angryavian I know, my question is why

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**  Arrange the five women in a row.  This can be done in $5!$ ways.  Doing so creates six spaces in which we can place the men, four between successive pairs of women and two at the ends of the row.

$$\square W \square W \square W \square W \square W \square$$

To ensure that no two of the men are adjacent, we must select five of these six spaces in which to place the men, which can be done in $\binom{6}{5}$ ways.  The men can be arranged in the selected spaces in $5!$ ways.  Hence, the number of seating arrangements of five men and five women in which no two of the men are seated next to each other is
$$5!\binom{6}{5}5! = 86400$$

**Method 2:**  We use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to correct your attempt, which is incorrect since you are subtracting cases in which there is more than one pair of adjacent men multiple times.

Rather than arranging men and women, we will count the number of arrangements of five Ms and five Ws in a row in which no pair of Ms are consecutive, then multiply our result by the number of ways of arranging five men in the positions occupied by the Ms and the number of ways of arranging five women in the positions occupied by the the Ws.

An arrangement of five Ms and five Ws is completely determined by choosing which five of the ten positions are occupied by the Ms since the remaining five positions must be occupied by Ws.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{10}{5}$$
possible arrangements of five Ms and five Ws.  From these, we must subtract those arrangements in which one or more pairs of Ms are adjacent.

*A pair of Ms is adjacent*:  We have nine objects to arrange: MM, M, M, M, W, W, W, W, W.  Choose one of the nine positions for MM and three of the remaining eight positions for the three single Ms.  This can be done in
$$\binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{3}$$

However, if we subtract this from the total, we will have subtracted too much since we will have subtracted each arrangement in which there are two pairs of adjacent Ms twice, once for each way of designating one of those pairs as the pair of adjacent Ms.  Since we only want to subtract these cases once, we must add them to the total.

*Two pairs in which a pair of Ms is adjacent*:  This can occur in two ways.  The pairs may be overlapping (three consecutive Ms) or disjoint.

Two overlapping pairs of adjacent Ms:  We have eight objects to arrange: MMM, M, M, W, W, W, W, W.  Choose one of the eight positions for MMM and two of the remaining six positions for the two single Ms, which can be done in
$$\binom{8}{1}\binom{6}{2}$$
ways.

Two disjoint pairs of adjacent Ms:  We again have eight objects to arrange: MM, MM, M, W, W, W, W, W.  Choose two of the eight positions for the MMs and one of the remaining six positions for the single M, which can be done in
$$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{1}$$
ways.

However, if we add these cases to the total, we will not have subtracted those cases in which there are three pairs of adjacent Ms.  This is because we subtracted them three times, once for each of the three ways of designating one of the pairs of adjacent Ms as the pair of adjacent Ms, and added them three times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of designating two of the three pairs of adjacent Ms as the two pairs of adjacent Ms.  Thus, we must subtract them from the total.

*Three pairs in which a pair of Ms is adjacent*:  This can occur in two ways.  The three pairs overlap (in which case there are four consecutive Ms) or there are two overlapping pairs and another pair which is disjoint from the overlapping pairs.

Three overlapping pairs:  We have seven objects to arrange: MMMM, M, W, W, W, W, W.  Choose one of the seven positions for the MMMM and one of the remaining six positions for the M, which can be done in
$$\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1}$$
ways.

Two overlapping pairs and a pair disjoint from the overlapping pairs:  We again have seven objects to arrange:  MMM, MM, W, W, W, W, W.  Choose one of the seven positions for the MMM and one of the remaining six positions for the MM, which can be done in
$$\binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1}$$
ways.

However, if we subtract these cases from the total, we will have subtracted too much.  This is because we have subtracted each case in which there are four pairs of consecutive Ms twice.  This is because we first subtracted such cases four times, once for each ways of designating one of those pairs as the pairs of adjacent Ms; then added them six times, once for each of the $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of designating two of those four pairs as the two pairs of adjacent Ms; then subtracted them four times, once for each of the $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of designating three of those four pairs as the three pairs of adjacent Ms.  Since we only want to subtract the cases in which there are four pairs of adjacent Ms once, we must add them to the total.

*Four pairs of adjacent Ms*:  Since there are a total of five Ms, this can only occur if all five Ms are consecutive.  We have six objects to arrange: MMMMM, W, W, W, W, W.  Choose which of the six positions is occupied by MMMMM, which can be done in
$$\binom{6}{1}$$
ways.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of arrangements of M, M, M, M, M, W, W, W, W, W in which no two Ms are consecutive is
$$\binom{10}{5} - \binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{3} + \binom{8}{1}\binom{6}{2} + \binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{1} - \binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1} - \binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1} + \binom{6}{1} = 6$$

Multiplying by the $5!$ ways we can arrange the men in the positions occupied by Ms and the $5!$ ways we can arrange the women in the positions occupied by Ws gives
$$\left[\binom{10}{5} - \binom{9}{1}\binom{8}{3} + \binom{8}{1}\binom{6}{2} + \binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{1} - \binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1} - \binom{7}{1}\binom{6}{1} + \binom{6}{1}\right]5!5! = 86,400$$
as above.

Answer (score 0):

The first task is to decide were to *place* men and women so that at least one woman is placed between each man, (in doing so, decide which of these six spaces to put the remaining woman place:  $\rm\_mw\_mw\_mw\_mw\_m\_$).
$$\rm wmwmwmwmwm\\ mwwmwmwmwm\\\ddots\\ mwmwmwmwmw$$

Then count ways to put the five distinct males and five distinct females in each from these arrangements of places.

Thus the answer of 86,400 is obtained.

---

> My idea was to count the number of ways I can seat them all with 2 men being together and subtract *(from)* $10!$.

${_5\mathsf P_2}\cdot 9!$ appears to be attempting to count ways to select and arrange a pair of men, then arrange that pair and eight singletons into the same line. This does not consider that more than two pairs might form, or even triples ...

Comment: My idea was inspire on the fact that $$ P(A^c) = 1 - P(A)$$ therefore $$ (\# \text{ways to arrange so not 2 men together})$$  $$ =$$ $$ (\text{total permutations}) - (# \text{ways to arrange so at least 2 men are together)$$

Comment: Yes, that idea is okay.  The issue is your miscounting of the complement would not distinguish $\sf AB,C,...$ from $\sf A,BC...$ (select Adam and Ben into a pair, then place them before to Carl, versus selecting Ben and Carl into a pair and placing them after Adam), or arrangements of $\sf..AB,..,C,D..$ from $\sf..A,B,..,CD,...$ and so forth.

Comment: ohhhh yeah such a great example, thanks man

Comment: The Law for Complementary Events *is* a useful tool, but only helpful when it is easier to evaluate the probability for the complement.

Answer (score 0):

> First, just arrange only the $5$ men in a line. You can do that in $5!=120$ ways, number of permutations of $5$ distinct objects.

> Take **any such permutation**, call it $A,B,C,D,E$ and note that now you can place the women in the spaces denoted as $$\_,A,\_,B,\_,C,\_,D,\_,E,\_$$ Let the number of women placed in the $i^{th}$ space be $a_i$. Then $$a_1\ge 0; \ a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5 > 0 ; \ a_6 \ge 0 \\ \text{and    }\ \ \ \ \ a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6=5$$
> which is same as saying $$a_1\ge 0; \ a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5 \ge 1 ; \ a_6 \ge 0 \implies a_1, a_2-1,a_3-1,a_4-1,a_5-1,a_6\ge 0 \\ \text{and    }\ \ \ \ \ a_1+(a_2-1)+(a_3-1)+(a_4-1)+(a_5-1)+a_6=1$$

> Now the question is, how many such combinations of $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_6)$ are there? Basically you have to find the [number of non-negative integral solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/919676/260674) to the equation $a+b+c+d+e+f=1$, which can be obtained by the formula in the above link (or by simply observing that at one of the variables has to be $1$ and the rest $0$) to be **6**.

> For each of these $6$ solutions, you can arrange the $5$ women in a line in $5!=120$ ways and divvy them up as the solutions $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)$ in $6\times 5!=720$ ways.

> The $720$ ways you have got for arranging the women, is for "**any such permutation**" from step 2. How many were there? There were $120$ of them (from step 1). So you have a total of $720\times 120=86400$ ways.

As for why your idea wouldn't work in it's current form (and would need a refinement by the principle of inclusion-exclusion) is you have removed the possibility $MWMMWMMWWW$ as many times as $MM$ occurs for this permutation, for each of the $9!$(?, should have been 8!, because you are fixing the positions of $2$ [if I am reading it right]) ways the remaining $9$ people could fit in this *invalid* permutation, which obviously removes each *invalid* permutation multiple times from the total of $10!$ and makes it negative.

Comment: Thank you, that was useful. You are right about my idea, i should give it up. How did you got that idea? I mean your inspiration and Is "the method you used" commonly powerful? Does it worth to learn it?

Comment: @OsvaldoEstrada I'm not really saying your idea wouldn't work. It would definitely work if you used the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion properly, and would involve some nasty calculations. On the aside, combinatorics problems usually require a wide array of methods, many are well-known of course, but you can't learn all of them *other than by practising LOTS of different kinds of problems which will build up your intuition to guess which method works where*.

Comment: Yeah, it may work but as you said by involving so many calculations and i was looking for an easy way

Comment: Yes, the method I have used is just working it step-by-step, counting in an orderly manner. It's just breaking up the problem into little easier parts so that doing counting on these little parts is easier, and you can combine all of it to get the final answer.