# How many possible ordered triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are there such that $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$ are non-negative integers and $x_1+x_2+x_3=38$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many possible ordered triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are there such that $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$ are non-negative integers and $x_1+x_2+x_3=38$?

Can someone explain the question and the working? Not too sure on how to start it. The answer is $780$. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Question is just asking you to find arrangements of $3$ non-negative integers (zero and positive integers) that sum to $38$. For example $x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 38$; $x1 = 38, x2 = 0, x3 = 0$ etc. Stars and bars is a standard method to solve such problems, pls go through the link shared by Matti P.

Comment: also see https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919676/the-number-of-integer-solutions-of-equations

Answer (score 1):

It is the question about permutation with multiset. The number of arrangements of $38$ times $1$ and two $+$ symbols.

$$\frac{40!}{38!\times2!}$$