# How many possible ordered triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are there such that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are nonnegative integers and $x_1 + x_2 +x_3 = 38$?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer I found was $5184$, but the apparent correct answer was $780$.

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: Is it answer of your question 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901553/how-many-possible-ordered-triples-x-1-x-2-x-3-are-there-such-that-x-1-x-2/3901563#3901563

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected you include your own thoughts on the problem.  How did you arrive at the answer $5184$?  Where are you stuck?